# What is the difference between these two lines of codes?

Tags: r

What is the difference between these two? Why do they have different outputs? Thanks!

```
(66.2-65)/(4.2/8) %>%
  pt(63)

((66.2-65)/(4.2/8)) %>%
  pt(63)
```

Comment: If you are not familiar with R's operator precedence, check out the `?Syntax` help page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case `(4.2/8) %>% pt(63)` happens first. Let

```
a <- (66.2-65)
b <- (4.2/8)
```

### Case 1

```
(66.2-65)/(4.2/8) %>% pt(63)
[1] 1,716034

a/pt(b,63)
[1] 1,716034
```

### Case 2

```
((66.2-65)/(4.2/8)) %>% pt(63)
[1] 0,987177

pt(a/b,63)
[1] 0,987177
```

So, we have `a/pt(b,63)` x `pt(a/b,63)`